# trying to display image on my html page when I view it in Codepen.io, but I just get a broken link

Tags: html

> I am trying to display a picture on my HTML page from my travels, but it just shows the broken link icon and my alt information for the photo instead. What am I doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
<img src="" alt="Uzbekistan12">" alt="Uzbekistan12">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because, the path of the image that you have mentioned in **src** is referring to a local image of your system.
Try to upload the image to cloud, and then mention the image link in **src**, this should work even if you try to view it on codepen.

Comment: Okay, so now I uploaded this image to the cloud, but it still shows a broken link: <img src="https://photos.app.goo.gl/QHR2v1Zxz7DEmgBWA" alt="Uzbekistan12">

Comment: make sure the cloud image is viewable by anyone who has the link!

Answer (score 1):

Your Codepen doesn't have access to your local storage (C: in this case).

Instead upload the photo online and use its URL in `src`.